# Fetching an array of objects with binary files from Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch, gridfs

I'm reading an array with text and image objects from my Node/MongoDB backend to my React frontend with the Fetch API.

Here's the structure of the array that needs to be read.

```
{
   _id: 616f9059791382150cf0f62a,
   title: 'stuff ',
   body: 'things!',
   ref: '537ac166131f94a4065e34508afmomf0.PNG',
   _createdBy: 61685a8e575fe41d48bb0fa2,
   created: 2021-10-20T03:43:21.605Z,
   __v: 0
 }
 {
   _id: 6170c39aba8eea4a982d6c1c,
   title: 'test',
   type: 'image',
   ref: '533dc166131f94a4065e34508afdadf1.PNG',
   _createdBy: 61685a8e575fe41d48bb0fa2,
   created: 2021-10-21T01:34:18.830Z,
   __v: 0
 }
```

Each ref is a reference to an image stored in GridFS that needs to be linked to the corresponding object.

What's the best way to do this? Should I .map through each object, and stream each object with its corresponding image one at a time to the frontend?

Should I upload the array first, then the stream a second array of images, then assign images to objects on the frontend?

Or maybe combine them in the backend, then stream it all as one giant array?

I'm new to binary data. Any guidance or suggested reading is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to fetch the image data on the server, rather than fetch it on the client using the URL? That adds a lot of resource load, cost, and bottleneck to your server, for something that is better off distributed on a CDN (cheaper, faster), and you would also need to serialize (slow) the binary into a larger string for a JSON response so it might be best to have a separate endpoint in either case. Also you might not need to fetch the image data unless it's visible - again leading to the best solution being to fetch the image on the client.

Comment: The image is stored on our own database, therefore can only be read from the server. Where would you suggest it be stored to be given a reachable URL?

Comment: Ah I see, I would suggest storing it as a file depends what hosting you have - GCP/AWS have file storage "buckets", or you can store it in a folder on your server and place a CDN like cloudflare in front of it, and your DB just has the filename to them